# Ruby on Rails: Each Loop, Separate resulting hash with comma within an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a hash using an each loop as follows:

```
[
  hash = session[:cart].each do |product|
  price = product[0].price.to_i*100
  {
    name: product[0].name, description: product[0].description, quantity: product[1], amount: product[0].price
  }, #Is it possible to add a comma here? Doing this normally causes an error
  end
]
```

Which should hopefully produce this Output

**Output**

```
 [
   {name: "Hellow", description: "Many Hellows", quantity: 1, price: 1000},
   {name: "Hellow", description: "Many Hellows", quantity: 1, price: 1000}
 ]
```

Comment: In your hash, you wrote: "amount: price: product[0].price". Is that a typo?

Comment: And no. No need to put the comma at the end.

Comment: oh yes, that's a typo, let me correct it. i'm trying to use activemerchant and it seems to only accept the multiple hashes if there's a comma separating the hashes D: ... which is the point really since all of these will be in an array

Comment: Sorry for the unclear message again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `.map`, not `.each`. Each iterates. Map translates one thing into another.

```
[
  session[:cart].map do |product|
    price = product[0].price.to_i*100
    {
      name: product[0].name,
      description: product[0].description,
      quantity: product[1],
      amount: product[0].price
    } 
  end
]
```

Comment: Changing it to map seem to still seem to cause  syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end ... any ideas ? :O

Comment: @Kishe No comma. That comma after the last `}` has no meaning and is syntactically invalid.

Comment: Bonus Question: What if they need to be separated within an array as the edit above. (I'm really sorry i didn't mention this earlier)

Comment: @Kishe  Then get rid of the `hash = ` part, and wrap the whole thing in `[]`. Please stop changing your question. If you have a new question, ask a new question, don't continually change the meaning of your old question.

Comment: @maegar Yessir. sorry about that.

Comment: @maegar That still doesn't separate the hashes within the array with a comma , though.